# How to confirm that a file object is empty? [Python]

Tags: python, file, is-empty

in a py module, I write:

```
outFile = open(fileName, mode='w')
if A:
    outFile.write(...)
if B:
    outFile.write(...)
```

and in these lines, I didn't use flush or close method.
Then after these lines, I want to check whether this "outFile" object is empty or not. How can I do with it?

Comment: in the mode `'r'` , you can't use `write()`.

Comment: when you say, "is empty", just what do you mean?  do you mean "has the data I've written reached disk yet?" or maybe "After all of that, did I actually try to write anything?"

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Even I think he's talking about the data that is not flushed yet.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I mean I want to ensure whether I've really write something into the file object, before I'm going to flush to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already written to the file, you can use `.tell()` to check if the current file position is nonzero:

```
>>> handle = open('/tmp/file.txt', 'w')
>>> handle.write('foo')
>>> handle.tell()
3
```

This won't work if you `.seek()` back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: So, if I use file.seek(0,2) then file.tell() and tell() returns 0, does it mean the file is empty?

Comment: @ThunderEX: No, it just means that the current position in the file is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. You can't `.write` to a file that you opened with `'r'`. You need to `open(fileName, 'w')`.
2. If `A or B` then you've certainly written to the file, so it's not empty!

Barring those. you can get the length of a file with

```
os.stat(outFile.fileno())
```

---

EDIT: I'll explain what `flush` does. Python is often used to do quite large amounts of file reads and writes, which can be slow. It is thus tweaked to make them as fast as possible. One way that is does so is to "buffer" such writes and then do them all in one big block: when you write a small string, Python will remember it but won't actually write it to the file until it thinks it should.

This means that if you want to tell whether you have written data to the file *by inspecting the file*, you have to tell Python to write all the data it's remembering first, or else you might not see it. `flush` is the command to write all the buffered data.

Of course, if you ask Python whether it's written anything to the file, say by inspecting the position in the file (`.tell()`), then it will know about the buffering.

Comment: re: #2, not neccesarily, `outFile.write('')` didn't write a thing!

Comment: Re: (2) -- even if what's written is nonempty, that doesn't mean `st_size` is nonzero yet.  I just did a test, writing `"z"` to a file and then calling `os.stat` immediately, and got `st_size=0`.  [P.S. I think `os.stat` accepts a path, not a `fileno`.]

Comment: Agreed with all comments =)

Comment: Well, because I haven't flushed yet, I think it did not really write to the disk. So getting file attribute may not be useful.

Comment: @DSM so how can I ensure whether the file object is written?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) to get file info:

```
import os
fileSize = os.stat(fileName).st_size
```

Comment: But this wouldn't be from the file object

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.txt", "r+") as f:
    if f.read(): 
        # file isn't empty
        f.write("something")
        # uncomment this line if you want to delete everything else in the file
        # f.truncate()
    else:
        # file is empty
        f.write("somethingelse")
```

"r+" mode always you to read & write.
"with" will automatically close file

Comment: You can have f.read(size) so that you don't load the entire file in memory just to check if it's empty, e.g. f.read(10)